# Have Cucumber Step Verify Variable Set By A Page Object In Another Step

Tags: ruby, cucumber, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I am using Cheezy's PageObject to setup some cucumber tests. I have everything pretty much setup like Jeff Morgan's book "Cucumber & Cheese".

Right now I have a page object "PublishPage" setup that has a method that sets a variable @tag. For example I have in the file publish_page.rb

```
Class PublishPage
  def tag
  #some steps left out
  @tag = "123"
  end

  def verify_tag
  #some steps left out
  @tag.should include "2"
  end
end
```

In the Cucumber steps, for one of the steps i have `on_page(PublishPage).tag`, and then in another step i have `on_page(PublishPage).verify_tag`. In my env.rb file I have `require 'rspec-expectations'`.

The problem is that when I run this code I get an error that says `undefined method 'include' for #<PublishPage:xxxxxx>`. But if I move the code inside the verify_tag method into the steps everything works except it does not have access to @tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be as simple as adding

```
include RSpec::Matchers
```

to your page object.

The other alternative would be to expose `@tag` through some method and then in your Cucumber step say something like

```
on_page(PublishPage).the_displayed_tag.should include("2")
```

Comment: One error I'm getting now "cannot convert nil to string" and I'm sure it is related to the instance variable @tag. I'm not sure why it is doing this because the method `tag` is being ran in another step before `verify_tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you invoke on_page(PublishPage), it will instantiate a new page object. You are most likely getting the "cannot convert nil to string" error because you are referencing an instance variable from a new object, hence it's value being nil. You should no longer get that error if you instantiate your page object only once, between calling page.tag and page.verify_tag.

Doing things this way will use one instance of your page object, allowing you to persist between step definitions.

```
When /I publish a tag/ do
   #on_page(PublishPage).tag
   @publish_page = PublishPage.new @browser
   @publish_page.tag
end

Then /I should have my tag/ do
   @publish_page.verify_tag 
end
```

Hope this helps!